# spring cloud config split application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I know that we can use application.properties to store shared/common property values. In our case the application.properties is becoming pretty big. Any way to split application.properties into multiples, just to help with manageability.

Thanx,

Comment: one way is to use many profiles, so many files as '`application-profile1.properties`,`application-profile2.properties` can be loaded and merged, but I dont want if its appropriate in your case.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Not sure if profile route will interfere with anything else. Profile is more of an envoronment right..prod, qa1..etc. right ? I will try it out anyways.